# Can't send notification minio to rabbitMQ (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, amqp, minio

#### Scenario:

I use docker compose and i can't send notification `minio` to `rabbitMQ` I have the following `rabbitmq.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        ports:
            # the management port
            - 5672:5672
            - 15672:15672
            # the stomp port
            - 61613:61613
```

and the following `minio.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  minio:
    image: 'bitnami/minio:latest'
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    environment:
      - MINIO_NOTIFY_AMQP_ENABLE=on   
      - MINIO_NOTIFY_AMQP_URL='amqp://guest:guest@192.168.1.2:15672'

    volumes:
      - 'minio_data:/data'

volumes:
  minio_data:
    driver: local
```

#### The problem is:

when i upload new file in `minio` server i don't receive notification in `rabbitMQ`.

I've already tried to change IP in `MINIO_NOTIFY_AMQP_URL` param to 127.0.0.1 but no result.

Is there a way to configure my docker-compose file (`minio.yml`, `rabbit.yml`) .

Comment: I dont know `MINIO` but shouldn't it be `amqp://guest:guest@192.168.1.2:5672`. Port `15672` is the web management console, and port `5672` is rabbitmq listeningen.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a docker network to connect both services. This could be done by specifiying `network` for both services.

You can then use the service name (in this case `rabbitmq`) as a host address:

`MINIO_NOTIFY_AMQP_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672`

Also note that the port should be `5672`, just as @frank-nielsen recommended.

```
version: '2'

services:
  minio:
    image: 'bitnami/minio:latest'
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    network:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MINIO_NOTIFY_AMQP_ENABLE=on   
      - MINIO_NOTIFY_AMQP_URL='amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672'

    volumes:
      - 'minio_data:/data'

network:
  backend:
    external: true

volumes:
  minio_data:
    driver: local
```

and the same for your rabbitmq config.

You will have to create the network using

```
docker network create backend
```

Comment: I have properly set these up but minio still cannot dial tcp connection.

‍‍‍minio1_1    | Error: dial tcp 172.18.0.2:5672: connect: connection refused (*net.OpError)‍‍‍

Comment: How do you run rabbitmq? Is it also running in docker? Make sure that they share the same network.

Comment: They are accessible in the same docker netwok and also I can ping 2 container with their hostname but minio fails in first try when rabbitmq is not ready and it does not try again later when the rabbitmq is up.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is not that minio is unable to connect to the IP but rather that at the time of connecting, rabbitmq is not yet ready. To avoid this, you can use depends_on in combination with a health check on rabbitmq: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on

Comment: As for the healthcheck, you might want to try this: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/docker-compose-healthcheck-for-rabbitmq#12200

Comment: Hm, seems like starting with docker-compose version 3, this feature has been removed and depends_on does no longer obey healthchecks. However, I am unable to test this currently.